# Django Rest Framework HTML POST form giving error message This field is required after submitting

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

My models.py is

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.genre


class Movies(models.Model):
    popularity=models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    director = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, blank=True, null=True)
    score= models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is my Serializer and viewset

```
# Serializers define the API representation.
class MoviesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #genre =  serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    genre =  serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=Genre.objects.all(),many=True,slug_field='genre' )
    class Meta:
        model = Movies
        fields = ('popularity', 'director', 'genre', 'score','name')

# ViewSets define the view behavior.
class MovieViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Movies.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MoviesSerializer

# Routers provide an easy way of automatically determining the URL conf.
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'movies', MovieViewSet)
```

I am able to see the HTML POST form while logged in as `Superuser`. But while submitting `HTML POST` form getting error message `This field is required`.  What is the error here in the code. Thanks for help in Advance.

[image][image]

Comment: are you sure that your `Movie` object has `Genre` object?

Comment: How to check that. I am able to select  one or many `Genre` object while creating a new `Movie` in `django`  `admin` section

Comment: Also for rest api call on a `movie` I am getting the `Genre` objects that I have selected. `[
    {
        "popularity": "1.89",
        "director": "Dib",
        "genre": [
            "test1",
            "test2"
        ],
        "score": "2.80",
        "name": "Test Movie"
    }
]`

Comment: could you add a screenshots or the complete error message. I don't understand "But for Genre dropdown I cant see any options. Getting msg No items to select. " where is this dropdown? add template, screenshots to help us to understand please

Comment: I have added screenshots . For the second screen `HTML POST form` see the `Genre` dropdown `No Item to Select `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [SlugRelatedField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) instead of the StringRelatedField for that.

Comment: I have already tried that `genre =  serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True,read_only=True,slug_field='genre' )` But for this even the `Genre` drop down field is not coming in the `HTML POST  Form `

Comment: Your line won't work with `read_only=True` Set the query set instead

Comment: Also now I am not able to create a new `movie` using `POST FORM `. Getting validation error `This field is required.` for all fields after submitting. Though I have provided values for all the filed .

Comment: You likely are using DRF 3.3.0 which has a bug. If this is you case, upgrade DRF to 3.3.1